# can we pass null in the url parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Asp.Net webApi controller as below:

```
[RoutePrefix("business/api/v1")]
public class BusinessController : ApiController
{


    [Route("GetDetails/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    { 
        // get business details code.
      } 
  }
```

Is there anyway that client can hit this api with id null??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your configuration of Web API routes in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs.

If route is something like:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "business/api/v1/GetDetails/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
```

then user can reach resource use `http://localhost.business/api/v1/GetDetails` or `http://localhost.business/api/v1/GetDetails/1`.

When you remove `defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }` then user have to pass an `id` otherwise, it will return 404

Comment: no the id parameter is not optional.. I am using attribute routing.. how to see if I have made it as optional in attribute routing?

Comment: Do you want to make `id` optional or not? See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

Comment: So, if you do not have this line: `defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }` then user have to always pass `id`. When they pass nothing(null) then it will return 404

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
[RoutePrefix("business/api/v1")]
public class BusinessController : ApiController
{       
    [Route("GetDetails/{id:int?}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    { 
        // get business details code.
    } 
}
```